# Create HTML table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

My question will ultimately be related to this site:

http://dbtest.net16.net/ethanol-01.html

EDIT: View unencrypted page source code here >>> http://dbtest.net16.net/ethanol-22.html

This is an HTML form with results calculated using JavaScript.  My goal is to display a table of 2-6 columns and variable number of rows depending on user input (form would be modified).  My problem is that I am not fully understanding how to get the table created in JavaScript after the user clicks the Calculate button.  I have found some potential good answers but apparently don't fully understand it all.  Running the following code is somewhat like what I want my output to display.

```
<html>
    <!-- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0220__Array/OutputarrayelementinaHTMLtableformat.htm -->

    <head>
        <title>Table of Numbers</title>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1>Table of Numbers</h1>

        <table border="0">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                <!--

                var myArray = new Array();
                myArray[0] = 1;
                myArray[1] = 2.218;
                myArray[2] = 33;
                myArray[3] = 114.94;
                myArray[4] = 5;
                myArray[5] = 33;
                myArray[6] = 114.980;
                myArray[7] = 5;

                document.write("<tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>Col Head 1</td>");
                document.write("<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 2</td>");
                document.write("<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 3</td></tr>");

                document.write("<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>---------------</td>");
                document.write("<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>");
                document.write("<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>");

                for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    document.write("<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>Number " + i + " is:</td>");
                    myArray[i] = myArray[i].toFixed(3);
                    document.write("<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td>");
                    document.write("<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td></tr>");
                }

                 //-->
            </script>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

If I can get the test table to be created and populated with my test data using my actual javascript file, then I should then be able to figure the rest myself (I think).

Following are a couple of the best answers I could find so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/YAXDZ/

The above link originated in stackoverflow but I can't seem to find the original post at this time.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0220__Array/OutputarrayelementinaHTMLtableformat.htm

Any help is appreciated.  Simpler is better due to my limited experience.

Comment: Ahh, haven't seen `document.write` and that way of setting an Array for a while...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that if you try to write a `<table>` or a `<tr>` or `<td>` tag using JS every time you insert a new tag the browser will try to close it as it will think that there is an error on the code.

Instead of writing your table line by line, concatenate your table into a variable and insert it once created:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

var myArray    = new Array();
    myArray[0] = 1;
    myArray[1] = 2.218;
    myArray[2] = 33;
    myArray[3] = 114.94;
    myArray[4] = 5;
    myArray[5] = 33;
    myArray[6] = 114.980;
    myArray[7] = 5;

    var myTable= "<table><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>Col Head 1</td>";
    myTable+= "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 2</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 3</td></tr>";

    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;                   '>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td     style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";

  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>Number " + i + " is:</td>";
    myArray[i] = myArray[i].toFixed(3);
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>" + myArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
  }  
   myTable+="</table>";

 document.write( myTable);

//-->
</script>
```

If your code is in an external JS file, in HTML create an element with an ID where you want your table to appear:

```
<div id="tablePrint"> </div>
```

And in JS instead of `document.write(myTable)` use the following code:

```
document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Use `document.body.appendChild`.

Comment: Thanks all so far. My major problem is creating the table.  Eddy - does your code create the table?  Derek - I'll have to study up on the document.body.appendChild as I am a hobbyist.  The code above was for testing output and formatting only.

Comment: It worked standalone in it's own HTML file but not when incorporating into my javascript code for further testing.  See my website link near top of original post.

Comment: Dont use document.write on an external JS file, unless it is being called from a function in HTML, instead try to insert the code useing appendChild or innerHTML, for example, create a division with an id "myDiv" and on JS use document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = myTable;

Comment: Yes my code creates the table inside the variable myTable. then is written into HTML, as I said before if you are using the code in an external JS file use innerHTML or appendChild by selecting an element with an ID, I will change my answer with more explanation

Comment: Thanks much.  I'll have to study further ref your tips so that I understand it further before I can proceed.  The JS file is being called when the user clicks the Calculate button.

Comment: Thanks Eddy.  I see some edits which I will check out further later when I have more time.  I think I understand where that is going.

Comment: @eddy Your sample code above worked except that I had to move </table> out of the loop for formatting purposes.  Now I can move forward.  Still a work in progress.  The sample test page can be viewed at <http://dbtest.net16.net/ethanol-22.html> and the table displays at bottom after clicking the Calculate button.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are 100% right, the </table> should be outside the loop as we are only creating many table rows not many tables, my mistake, I fixed the code. I am glad you found the error, to be honest I didn't test it an I completely missed that one. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

This beautiful code here creates a table with each td having array values. Not my code, but it helped me!

```
var rows = 6, cols = 7;

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
  for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    $('table').find('tr').eq(i).append('<td></td>');
    $('table').find('tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(j).attr('data-row', i).attr('data-col', j);
  }
}
```

Comment: It use Jquery. I think topic about Vanilla.

Comment: Thanks to both Ben Taylor & SLonoed.  I will check this out as time allows.  This may also come in handy elsewhere on another project.

Comment: Anybody wishing to view my semi-final working HTML and Javascript code (unencrypted) can view it hear:  http://dbtest.net16.net/ethanol-22.html  -- View the page source in your browser.  Note the Javascript code related to this topic is still quite sloppy and begins on approximately line 572.  It should be more readable if you remove all my commented lines.  Also note this page allows for building a table in either a new tab/window or at the bottom of current page, or no table at all.  This is controlled by the radio button selections in the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the html file there are three input boxes with userid,username,department respectively.
```

These inputboxes are used to get the input from the user.

The user can add any number of inputs to the page.

When clicking the button the script will enable the debugger mode.

In javascript, to enable the debugger mode, we have to add the following tag in the javascript.

/************************************************************************\

```
    Tools->Internet Options-->Advanced-->uncheck
    Disable script debugging(Internet Explorer)
    Disable script debugging(Other)

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

    <head runat="server">

    <title>Dynamic Table</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    // <!CDATA[

    function CmdAdd_onclick() {

    var newTable,startTag,endTag;



    //Creating a new table

    startTag="<TABLE id='mainTable'><TBODY><TR><TD style=\"WIDTH: 120px\">User ID</TD>
    <TD style=\"WIDTH: 120px\">User Name</TD><TD style=\"WIDTH: 120px\">Department</TD></TR>"

    endTag="</TBODY></TABLE>"

    newTable=startTag;

    var trContents;

    //Get the row contents

    trContents=document.body.getElementsByTagName('TR');

    if(trContents.length>1)

    {

    for(i=1;i<trContents.length;i++)

    {

    if(trContents(i).innerHTML)

    {

    // Add previous rows

    newTable+="<TR>";

    newTable+=trContents(i).innerHTML;

    newTable+="</TR>";

    } 

    }

    }

    //Add the Latest row

    newTable+="<TR><TD style=\"WIDTH: 120px\" >" +
        document.getElementById('userid').value +"</TD>";

    newTable+="<TD style=\"WIDTH: 120px\" >" +
        document.getElementById('username').value +"</TD>";

    newTable+="<TD style=\"WIDTH: 120px\" >" +
        document.getElementById('department').value +"</TD><TR>";

    newTable+=endTag;

    //Update the Previous Table With New Table.

    document.getElementById('tableDiv').innerHTML=newTable;

    }

    // ]]>

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

    <br />

    <label>UserID</label> 

    <input id="userid" type="text" /><br />

    <label>UserName</label> 

    <input id="username" type="text" /><br />

    <label>Department</label> 

    <input id="department" type="text" />

    <center>

    <input id="CmdAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="return CmdAdd_onclick()" />
    </center>



    </div>

    <div id="tableDiv" style="text-align:center" >

    <table id="mainTable">

    <tr style="width:120px " >

    <td >User ID</td>

    <td>User Name</td>

    <td>Department</td>

    </tr>

    </table>

    </div>

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```