# Populate table element using string

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a string like this:

```
var tablestring = "<table><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>";
```

Is it possible to populate a table DOM object doing something like this:

```
var Test = document.createElement("TABLE");
Test.value = tablestring;
```

Comment: Are you partial to using jQuery to achieve this? A jumping-off point might be in this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string

Comment: Kindly read the below link that may help you
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126357/create-html-table-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Using `.innerHTML` you can assign html to a dom element. Please see the snippet below:

```js
function addTable(){
 var tablestring = "<table><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>";
 var container = document.getElementById('container');
 container.innerHTML = tablestring;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addTable()"> Add table </button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
var tablestring = "<table><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>";

var Test = document.createElement("Div");
Test.innerHTML= tablestring;

document.body.appendChild(Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery solution

```
$("Your div").html(tablestring);
```

Comment: the JQ object doesn't have a `innerHTML` method maybe you meant `$(..)html('str')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.html()` in jQuery to add `tablestring` in div. It may be help to you.

```js
function addTable(){
 var tablestring = "<table class='table'><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>";
 $('#myTable').html(tablestring);
}
```

```css
.table{
  border:1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addTable()"> Add table </button>
<div id="myTable"></div>
```